# Ajax call to ASP.NET controller with one string param with NULL (0x00) char - receive null string in controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have CLOB values saved in a database. These CLOB values are html formatted texts. These clob values are in C# represented as a string and then there is an Ajax call to an ASP.NET controller, which takes one string argument and only generates modal window with given text.

It happened that I have in a CLOB value saved char 0x00 which is NULL char. In html form it is shown as a special character `�` which is fine. Problem is when string with this char is given to the Ajax call to  make a modal. In Ajax call payload the string is present, but on the controller side, it is a null.

Ajax:

```js
function loadNoteModal(data) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "@Url.Action("ShowStringModal", "Common")",
            data: {
                value: data
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //some proccessing
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert("error");
            }
    })
};
```

Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult ShowStringModal(string value)
{
    return PartialView("_NoteModal", value);
}
```

Is there any way to receive the payload in the controller unchanged?

I already tried to set some common content types but it did not do anything. I also tried to add `[HttpPost]` attribute to the controller method. Also `HttpGet` is not possible to use.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you need to call a controller at all since it's just reflecting back the value.  Hopefully this isn't untrusted user content...  why not let Javascript create the modal?

Comment: Let's say it is architectonical decision, to have as little javascript code as possible. It is just html formated text from db but possibly something more can be done on the controller side.

Comment: you could process it on the controller side, but what is the null character to be used for?  (Why is it there? What is the source?  What is the encoding?  Is this always UTF-8?)

Comment: @pcalkins the null character appeard in here from users that probably copied a text from somewhere. It is UTF-8.

Comment: it doesn't sound like you need it.  Just filter it out.  That would generally be a null-terminator in that context.  There's no display representation for that, but could be used as a line break depending on the output.

Comment: This would be of course the option to filter out this "char".  Question is where to create this filtering to have it well architecturally formed. But rather than that i would like still to be able to show the char (with the auto question mark char for unknown chars) because thre can be more these unkown chars that user copy from somewhere else. Also I would like to have working solution on existing saved data.

Comment: that's really up to the font...  if the font doesn't have a character for that encoded value, it might display a "?".   The source is important here if you want to try to filter the garbage.  Is the encoding always the same?  If not, you have to scan the input and try to make your best guess.  Even if the input were files you might have to do that, as some will have a "byte-order-marker" and some will not....